# Easy way to populate this matrix?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, fill

I would like to populate an `n * n` (n being odd) matrix in the following way:

```
_   _   _   23  22  21  20
_   _   24  10  9   8   37
_   25  11  3   2   19  36
26  12  4   1   7   18  35
27  13  5   6   17  34  _
28  14  15  16  33  _   _
29  30  31  32  _   _   _
```

What is an easy way to do this using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Can we assume that `n` is odd?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I am sorry, you certainly can.

Comment: Just curious: what are you going to use this for?

Comment: @Sjoerd it relates to one of the Project Euler problems, but it is not the crux.  I found the question of how to efficiently populate this construct an interesting question in itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With this helper function:

```
Clear[makeSteps];
makeSteps[0] = {};
makeSteps[m_Integer?Positive] :=
  Most@Flatten[
    Table[#, {m}] & /@ {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {0, -1}}, 1];
```

We can construct the matrix as

```
constructMatrix[n_Integer?OddQ] :=
  Module[{cycles, positions},
    cycles = (n+1)/2;
    positions = 
       Flatten[FoldList[Plus, cycles + {#, -#}, makeSteps[#]] & /@ 
           Range[0, cycles - 1], 1];
    SparseArray[Reverse[positions, {2}] -> Range[Length[positions]]]];
```

To get the matrix you described, use

```
constructMatrix[7] // MatrixForm
```

The idea behind this is to examine the pattern that the positions of consecutive numbers 1.. follow. You can see that these form the cycles. The zeroth cycle is trivial - contains a number 1 at position `{0,0}` (if we count positions from the center). The next cycle is formed by taking the first number (2) at position `{1,-1}` and adding to it one by one the following steps: `{0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}` (as we move around the center). The second cycle is similar, but we have to start with `{2,-2}`, repeat each of the previous steps twice, and add the sixth step (going up), repeated only once: `{0, -1}`. The third cycle is analogous: start with `{3,-3}`, repeat all the steps 3 times, except `{0,-1}` which is repeated only twice. The auxiliary function `makeSteps` automates the process.  In the main function then, we have to collect all positions together, and then add to them `{cycles, cycles}` since they were counted from the center, which has a position `{cycles,cycles}`. Finally, we construct the `SparseArray` out of these positions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I added some explanation

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One can remove double `Tranpose` and use `{cycles+#,cycles-#}&` instead of `{#,-#}&`, to make the code shorter, at the expense of some performance penalty.

Comment: How about `cycles+{#,-#}` ? :-)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know the Mathematica syntax but I guess you could use an algorithm like this:

```
start in the middle of the matrix
enter a 1 into the middle
go up-right (y-1 / x+1)
set integer iter=1
set integer num=2
while cursor is in matrix repeat:
   enter num in current field 
   increase num by 1
   repeat iter times:
       go left (x-1 / y)
       enter num in current field 
       increase num by 1
   repeat iter times:
       go down-left (x-1 / y+1)
       enter num in current field 
       increase num by 1
   repeat iter times:
       go down (x / y+1)
       enter num in current field 
       increase num by 1
   repeat iter times:
       go right (x+1 / y)
       enter num in current field 
       increase num by 1
   repeat iter times:
       go up-right (x+1 / y-1)
       enter num in current field 
       increase num by 1
   repeat iter-1 times:
       go up (x / y-1)
       enter num in current field 
       increase num by 1
   go up-up-right (y-2 / x+1)
   increase iter by 1
```

you can also pretty easily convert this algorithm into a functional version or into a tail-recursion.

Well, you will have to check in the while loop if you aren't out of bounds as well. If n is odd then you can just count num up while:

```
m = floor(n/2)
num <= n*n - (m+m*m)
```

I'm pretty sure that there's a simpler algorithm but that's the most intuitive one to me.

Comment: While something like this certainly works, and it's straightforward, I think the point of the question is how to leverage Mathematica's built-in functionality and functional programming contstructs to come up with something easier and more compact :-)

Comment: While I did my version independently, I just realized that this is the same algorithm I ended up with, just done procedurally. +1.

Comment: @Leonid I must admit that I got lost in the middle of reading this and thought "I'll just wait for a *Mathematica* answer."  PeterT: +1

Answer (score 4):

The magic numbers on the diagonal starting at 1 and going up right can be arrived at from

```
f[n_] := 2 Sum[2 m - 1, {m, 1, n}] + UnitStep[n - 3] Sum[2 m, {m, 1, n - 2}]

In  := f@Range@5
Out := {2, 8, 20, 38, 62}
```

With this it should be easy to set up a `SparseArray`. I'll play around with it a bit and see how hard that is.

Comment: You can reduce that to `2 - 3 n + 3 n^2`

Comment: Even simpler is the recursive definiton `f[-1]=2;f[i_]:=6i+f[i-1];`

Comment: As usual http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C8%2C20%2C38&sort=&language=english&go=Search :)

Comment: Going downwards by the big antidiagonal http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C14%2C29%2C50%2C77&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @belisarius Or `FindSequenceFunction[{2, 8, 20, 38}]`, but that's not something easy to trust (are the following numbers going to match too?)

Comment: @Sza I consider `FindSequenceFunction[]` as "work under development" :). WRI could try to link it to OEIS, if copyright allows.

Answer (score 4):

First version:

```
i = 10;
a = b = c = Array[0 &, {2 (2 i + 1), 2 (2 i + 1)}];
f[n_] := 3*n*(n + 1) + 1;
k = f[i - 2];
p[i_Integer] :=
  ToRules@Reduce[
    -x + y < i - 1 && -x + y > -i + 1 &&
     (2 i + 1 - x)^2 + (2 i + 1 - y)^2 <= 2 i i - 2 &&
     3 i - 1 > x > i + 1 &&
     3 i - 1 > y > i + 1, {x, y}, Integers];

((a[[Sequence @@ #]] = 1) & /@ ({x, y} /. {p[i]}));
((a[[Sequence @@ (# + {2, 2})]] = 0) & /@ ({x, y} /. {p[i - 1]}));

(b[[Sequence @@ #]] = k--)&/@((# + 2 i {1, 1}) &/@ (SortBy[(# - 2 i {1, 1}) &/@ 
       Position[a, 1], 
      N@(Mod[-10^-9 - Pi/4 + ArcTan[Sequence @@ #], 2  Pi]) &]));
c = Table[b[[2 (2 i + 1) - j, k]], {j, 2 (2 i + 1) - 1}, 
                                   {k, 2 (2 i + 1) - 1}];
MatrixPlot[c]
```

[image]

**Edit**

A better one:

```
genMat[m_] := Module[{f, k, k1, i, n, a = {{1}}},
  f[n_] := 3*n*(n + 1) + 1;
  For[n = 1, n <= m, n++,
   a = ArrayPad[a, 1];
   k1 = (f[n - 1] + (k = f[n]) + 2)/2 - 1;
   For[i = 2, i <= n + 1, i++,  a[[i, 2n + 1]] = k--; a[[2-i+2 n, 1]] = k1--];
   For[i = n + 2, i <= 2 n + 1, i++, a[[i, 3n+2-i]] = k--; a[[-i,i-n]] = k1--];
   For[i = n, i >= 1, i--, a[[2n+1, i]] = k--;a[[1, -i + 2 n + 2]] = k1--];
   ];
  Return@MatrixForm[a];
  ]

genMat[5]
```

Comment: That looks quite interesting; would you please explain it?

Comment: @Mr. The current code incarnation is still too convoluted. I'll clean it up and comment as soon as I get some free time. There are two main ideas there (nothing brillant) : 1) describe the "hexagon" geometrically and let Reduce[] find the edges and 2) Sort the edge elements by the angle subtended from the polygon center. The third idea is not mine f[n_] := 3*n*(n + 1) + 1 comes from here https://oeis.org/search?q=crystal+ball&language=english&go=Search

Comment: I cannot imagine this being highly efficient, but +1 for a completely different approach.

Comment: @Mr. I guess it will end up being quite efficient, as the geometric description is very simple once you draw it. Just look at my picture: 4 straight segments and two Pi/4 staircases. I'll remove the Reduce[] part. Then I will get rid of the SortBy[], because I'll build the edges in order, and I know the highest number is f[i-2]. So it will be three loops and O(n).

Comment: @Mr. Then you can enjoy that now

Answer (score 3):

A partial solution, using image procssing:

[image]

```
Image /@ (Differences@(ImageData /@ 
     NestList[
      Fold[ImageAdd, 
        p = #, (HitMissTransform[p, #, Padding -> 0] & /@
          {{{1}, {-1}},
           {{-1}, {-1}, {1}},
           {{1, -1, -1}},
           {{-1, -1, 1}},
           {{-1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1, -1}}, 
           {{-1, -1, -1,  1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1}}})] &, img, 4]))
```

[image]

Comment: Would [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/675/77) be of interest to you?

Comment: @yoda Nice question and not easy at all. I think one should try to recognize rotated ellipses.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave it a shot :) I can even bounty it to boost you up :D There's a few image processing questions floating around ([here's another interesting one](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/374/river-detection-in-text)), but not enough people knowledgable to answer it. A lot of folks are just posting half-assed answers...

Comment: @yoda Posted a partial answer

Comment: @yoda the second one was really easy

Comment: Yeah, that was fairly straightforward and was just a matter of converting thought to code. Still, that was an interesting question because of its application. Although I've known about publishers and TeX experts' efforts to avoid rivers, wouldn't have thought of combining image processing with latex. Also, please don't create a new chat room... gosh, I hate this nagging feature!

Comment: @yoda Agree about chat rooms. One is enough, and synchronous communication consumes a lot of time. Do you frequent dsp.stack... ? Is it worth?

Comment: I'm a moderator there :) I do visit it every day (Fanatic tomorrow!) and I used to answer some questions, but I'm in a time crunch these days (answers there take more of my time than elsewhere) and so am on a little break. We do have a serious problem with question volume (<200 in 100 days!) and that's worrying... Part of the reason for the lull is that we had low activity in private beta and they shunted us in there for 3 weeks before opening to the public... that kinda dampened spirits

Comment: Still, I think it has the potential to be a neat place for some theoretical concepts and solutions to problems (logic, not code). There are some decent questions and answers and I really hope image processing questions take off on the site. The name might be misleading for a lot of folks... hmm.

Comment: @yoda So you are a dsp expert! Nice! I wonder if you can give me some useful links to learn about wavelets. Basic an easy to read, I want to satisfy my curiosity, not becoming an expert

Comment: Haha! No, far from an expert! Re: wavelets, [these folks](http://www.wavelet.org/phpBB2/gallery.php) maintain a list of books on wavelets in different fields and varying degrees of mathematical intensity. The first three are fairly well known and introductory. Strang's book is often used as the textbook for graduate level courses (as with all textbooks, people have a love-hate relationship with that :P). However, I don't know enough about books that have a lot of practical examples (like in image processing), but I'll inquire and find a few if that's what you're after

Comment: Sometimes, when I'm trying to learn something new, I find the course material on MIT's Open Course Ware pretty helpful. [Here's the link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-327-wavelets-filter-banks-and-applications-spring-2003/lecture-notes/) for the Wavelets course. They use Strang's book (who also teaches it).

Comment: @yoda Thanks! I'll give feedback on those as soon as I regret my idea of learning wavelets :)